# Is it safe to use a boolean flag to stop a thread from running in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

My main concern is with the boolean flag... is it safe to use it without any synchronization? I've read in several places that it's atomic (including the documentation).

```
class MyTask
{
    private ManualResetEvent startSignal;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private bool running;

    MyTask(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        running = false;
        this.latch = latch;
        startSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    // A method which runs in a thread
    public void Run()
    {
        startSignal.WaitOne();
        while(running)
        {
            startSignal.WaitOne();
            //... some code
        }
        latch.Signal();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        running = false;
        startSignal.Set();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        running = true;
        startSignal.Set();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        startSignal.Reset();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        startSignal.Set();
    }
}
```

Is this a safe way to design a task in this way? Any suggestions, improvements, comments?

Note: I wrote my custom `CountDownLatch` class in case you're wondering where I'm getting it from.

**Update:**
Here is my CountDownLatch too:

```
public class CountDownLatch 
{
    private volatile int m_remain;
    private EventWaitHandle m_event;

    public CountDownLatch (int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        m_remain = count;
        m_event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        if (m_remain == 0)
        {
            m_event.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Signal()
    {
        // The last thread to signal also sets the event.
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_remain) == 0)
            m_event.Set();
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        m_event.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You better mark it [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28VS.80%29.aspx) though:

> The volatile keyword indicates that a
>   field might be modified by multiple
>   concurrently executing threads. Fields
>   that are declared volatile  are not
>   subject to compiler optimizations that
>   assume access by a single thread. This
>   ensures that the most up-to-date value
>   is present in the field at all times.

But I would change your loop:

```
    startSignal.WaitOne();
    while(running)
    {
        //... some code
        startSignal.WaitOne();
    }
```

As it is in your post the 'some code' might execute when the thread is *stopped* (ie. when Stop is called) which is unexpected and may be even incorrect.

Comment: @Remus Good catch in my while loop code order. Regarding the volatile flag: does it really make a difference if the flag is volatile in this case? If it misses the first update, then it's going to do one more run through the loop and catch it the next time around...

Comment: If you don't mark it volatile, the generated code might optimize the value into a registry and your thread will *never* see the change.

Comment: @Remus I get it now: the atomicity has nothing to do with the visibility between threads... just because an operation is executed in one CPU cycle it doesn't mean that the result will be visible to the other threads unless the value is marked volatile.

Comment: Since we're at it: your latch.Release() must be in a finally block. And since you wrote it yourself, you better make sure the latch is correct too, there could be a mirriad gotchats in that too.

Comment: @Remus I've updated my question and added the CountDownLatch, but I think it's fine... it's pretty simple and it has been working fine.

Comment: @Lirik: what you just said is extremely important so let's repeat it: **in the most general case, atomicity has nothing whatsoever to do with volatility**. The rules of *C#* are such that everything volatile is also atomic, but not the other way around; some things are atomic without being volatile. The CLR makes no such guarantee; in the CLR, volatility and atomicity are orthogonal. You can have nonatomic-nonvolatile, atomic-nonvolatile, nonatomic-volatile and atomic-volatile reads and writes.

Comment: @Eric That clarification is indeed **VERY** important.

Answer (score 6):

Booleans are atomic in C#, however, if you want to modify it in one thread and read it in another, you will need to mark it volatile at the very least,.  Otherwise the reading thread may only actually read it once into a register.

Comment: @Michael So how many cycles through the loop can realistically pass before the loop catches it? I assumed that it would be one, but I assume there is no such guarantee...

Comment: @Michael I got it now: I just realized that I was confusing atomicity with visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Booleans are atomic in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(VS.71).aspx

Comment: They are indeed atomic, but that doesn't mean that each thread has the most recent value in cache.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I just noticed this part of the code:

```
// A method which runs in a thread
    public void Run()
    {
        startSignal.WaitOne();
        while(running)
        {
            startSignal.WaitOne();
            //... some code
        }
        latch.Signal();
    }
```

You will need to unblock the worker thread twice using "startSignal.Set()" for the code within the while block to execute.

Is this deliberate?

Comment: @Akapetronics startSignal only needs to be set once. WaitOne doesn't reset the event, so I can call startSignal.WaitOne() multiple times and it will not block until startSignal.Reset() is called. The design is deliberate: the thread will block until the Start method is called and the Start method first sets the running flag and sets the startSignal so the while loop can begin execution. If I reverse the order and first set the startSignal then the while loop might exit before I even set the running flag. Notice that this design eliminates the need for locks.