# Stopping work from one thread using another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Not sure if my title is worded well, but whatever :)

I have two threads: the main thread with the work that needs to be done, and a worker thread that contains a form with a progress bar and a cancel button. In normal code, it would be the other way around, but I can't do that in this case.

When the user clicks the cancel button, a prompt is displayed asking if he wants to really cancel the work. The problem is that work continues on the main thread. I can get the main thread to stop work and such, but I would like for it to stop doing work when he clicks "Yes" on the prompt.

Example:

```
// Main thread work starts here    
    t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(progressForm_Start));
    t1.Start();

    // Working
    for (i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        if (pBar.Running)
            bgworker_ProgressChanged(i);
        semaphore.Release();
        if (pBar.IsCancelled) break; 
    }

    t1.Abort(); 
// Main thread work ends here

// Start progress bar form in another thread
void progressForm_Start()
{
    pBar.Status("Starting");
    pBar.ShowDialog();
}
```

I could theoretically include a prompt in the cancelWatch() function, but then I would have to do that everywhere I'm implementing this class.

Comment: Why can't you put the form in the main thread and simply use a Swing WorkerThread ? This looks as convoluted as it gets. Also what do you mean by "Normal Code"

Comment: By "Normal code" I meant how I would have thought of doing it at first.

I can't put the form in the main thread because I need to be able to actually click the Cancel button anytime to cancel the operation. But I can't use a BackgroundWorker because I don't want asynchronous threads here.

The main thread is already a form that displays data and does some stuff in the background. I need a progress bar and a cancel button on top of that, and doing it on the main form is pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a couple of quick comments:

1. Avoid using `Thread.Abort()` [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-thread-termination-and-thread-abort).
2. Make your thread a background thread: `Thread.IsBackground = true` (this will automatically exit the thread when your app exits).

Here is a detailed discussion on how to **safely** stop a thread from running: [Is it safe to use a boolean flag to stop a thread from running in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474945/is-it-safe-to-use-a-boolean-flag-to-stop-a-thread-from-running-in-c)

To stop the work on the main thread you'd have to do something like this:

```
boolean volatile isRunning = true;

static void Main(...)
{
    // ...
    // Working
    for (i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        if (!isRunning) break; // exit if not running
        if (pBar.Running)
            bgworker_ProgressChanged(i);
        semaphore.Release();
    }
    //...
    t1.Interrupt();// make the worker thread catch the exception
}
// 
void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isRunning = false; // optimistic stop
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll have to try this when I get a chance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you...we decided to try a different route, but thanks for the answer. It at least pointed us in the right direction :)

Comment: @Duracell, I'm glad my answer was helpful in some respect :).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx), which can handle this kind of complex scenario. It's part of the Task Parallel Library but does not actually have to be used with `Task` objects; it can just as easily be used with old-style `Thread` objects.

Of course, if you have the time, I'd recommend defining the main thread's work as a `Task` object (running on the main UI thread by using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`).

Note that everything above assumes .NET 4.0. If you're still stuck on the old platform, you'll just have to have a `bool cancelled;` field protected by a `lock` or some such thing. Tip: don't call `Thread.Abort`; it's evil.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're stuck on .NET 3.5, because this would be what I needed :( ... Thanks anyways!