# How to run two threads together and when one is terminated, automatically terminate other

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two functions. i need to start those on a single thread with two sides or on multiple threads, but i want them to be connected so one is terminated, terminate the other one too.

```
    public static void StartSocket()
    {
        Server myserver = new Server(*, ****);
    }
    public static void StartWeb()
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder().Build().Run();
    }
```

Example `

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(StartSocket);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(StartWeb);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
```

how to terminate t1 when t2 is terminated, and t2 when t1 is terminated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it would be helpful if you post your code where you actually run the threads.

Comment: @RobinB done sir.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so what is exactly meant by termination in your context? Do you want to abort `t2` if `t1` finishes first? Or do you just want to cancel both at the same time if a condition is met? (This should be solved by just calling `Abort()` on both of them.)

Comment: Take a look at this: [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort). For a solution, look at [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) instead of aborting threads.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks sir, will look for it now

Comment: @RobinB in this case t2 is a web app so it can be terminated by many cases, i just need to know it is canceled or closed

Comment: Have you take a look to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345481/how-to-stop-one-thread-when-the-other-finishes

Comment: If I am right by assuming that `new Server(*,****);` and `CreateWebHostBuilder().Build().Run();` will block execution without you having the chance to somehow signal them to cancel I don't see any easy solution. You most likely want to rewrite both to allow cancelation with a token. It is possible to use `Thread.Abort()` here but you most likely do not want to just drop a thread while it is doing some network stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in this [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359927/734181), the [`Thread.Abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) is (severely) deprecated.

A most elegant way of doing this would be to use cancellation token on `async` Tasks.

The only drawback is it does not provide any notifications and you have to monitor it yourself using `IsCancellationRequested` or `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. But on the other hand it is quite handy and easy to accomplish.

A very basic sample:

```cs
public class TaskCompletionTests
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;
    public TaskCompletionTests(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TerminateOtherWhenOneCompleted()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var waitForCompletionDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        var executionWaitingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        var smallerWaitingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        // Act
        var taskOne = Task.Run(DoSomething("T1", executionWaitingDelay, cancellationSource), cancellationSource.Token);

        var taskTwo = Task.Run(DoSomething("T2", smallerWaitingDelay, cancellationSource), cancellationSource.Token);

        await Task.WhenAny(taskOne, taskTwo);
        cancellationSource.Cancel();

        await Task.Delay(waitForCompletionDelay);
    }
    
    private Func<Task> DoSomething(string label, TimeSpan waitingDuration, CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource)
    {
        return async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // do the thing
                _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{label} working ...");
                // wait a bit ...
                await Task.Delay(waitingDuration, cancellationSource.Token);
                // checking for cancellation
                cancellationSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                // do more things ...
                _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{label} completed.");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{label} was aborted");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And output will be

> T1 working ... T2 working ... T2 completed. T1 was aborted

You can change the wait duration to test that having T1 completed first will also work.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Instead of `Thread.Sleep` it is preferable to use [`await Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay). As a bonus it accepts a `CancellationToken` as argument.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias I have updated the code based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is not adviced to stop a thread with Thread.Abort(), [C# Thread Termination and Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-sharp-thread-termination-and-thread-abort)

You should have a flag which indicates when you must terminate the thread, for example:

```
private static bool TerminateThreads = false;

public static void StartSocket()
{
    Server myserver = new Server(*, ****);
    while(!TerminateThreads) 
    { 
        try { ExecuteSomething();  }
        catch { TerminateThreads = true; }
    }
}
public static void StartWeb()
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder().Build().Run();
    while(!TerminateThreads) 
    { 
        try { ExecuteOtherSomething();  }
        catch { TerminateThreads = true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: About the `TerminateThreads` static field, shouldn't it be declared [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)?

Comment: How am i gonna create threads then sir?

            Thread t1 = new Thread(StartSocket);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(StartWeb);

to Execute them.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes indeed, i didn't knew about that, thanks.

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan you create those threads just the way you have, on the constructor of the class and then start them