# Asynchronous MultiThreaded bool value in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, locking, boolean

I'm trying to build a button that displays a loading circle and loads some data in a C# application.

I have a boolean value called `Loading` that tracks the state of the current data that is being loaded.

I have a delegate called `LoadHandler` that returns a boolean value based on whether the loading is complete or not, I also have an event that can be subscribed to in a separate class that takes the `LoadHandler` signature and handles the actual loading.

I have a `private Load()` function that gets called when an event handler for input is called in the base class, this is called on a `new Thread`.

Here's the code for the `LoadEntry` class (Keep in mind this is just a button that displays a loading circle when hit, and delegates loading to a separate class)

```
public class LoadingEntry : ButtonEntry
{
    private readonly object objLock = new object(); 

    /// <summary>
    /// The loading circle texutre
    /// </summary>
    Texture2D loadingReticle; 

    /// <summary>
    /// Tracks the rotation of the loading reticle.
    /// </summary>
    float loadingRotation;

    /// <summary>
    /// Tells whether we are loading or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool Loading { get; private set; } 

    public LoadingEntry(string buttonText)
        : base(buttonText)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler that will return true when loading information is complete
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /// <returns>True if loading is complete</returns>
    public delegate bool LoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e); 

    /// <summary>
    /// The LoadHandler event that should be subscribed to in a menu class 
    /// </summary>
    public event LoadHandler onLoad;

    private void Load()
    {
        if (onLoad != null)
        {
            lock (objLock)
            {
                Loading = true;
                while (true)
                {
                    Loading = onLoad(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    if (!Loading)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected internal override void OnSelectEntry(PlayerIndex playerIndex)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Load));
        t.Start(); 
        base.OnSelectEntry(playerIndex);
    }

    public override void Draw(MenuScreen screen, bool isSelected, GameTime gameTime, bool fade)
    {
        if (Loading)
        {
            loadingReticle = screen.ScreenManager.LoadingReticle; 

            Vector2 origin = new Vector2(loadingReticle.Width / 2, loadingReticle.Height / 2); 
            loadingRotation += 0.01f;

            screen.ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(loadingReticle, position, null, Color.White, loadingRotation, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f); 
        }
        else base.Draw(screen, isSelected, gameTime, fade);
    }
```

The base class `ButtonEntry` shouldn't be important.

And here's what is subscribed to `onLoad` in another class: (just for practice, this is where actual loading code would go)

```
    int sampleTics = 0; 
    bool sampleLoad_onLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        sampleTics++;
        if (sampleTics < 1000)
            return true;

        return false; 
    }
```

My question is am I using mulit-threading properly? The code doesn't even display the circle, I haven't done much testing yet because i'm going to bed. Is the lock necessary in this situation? Is there a better way to do this that i'm not seeing?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @AgentShark This is a Windows Phone 8 application, I believe I'm running .Net Compact Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to call `Thread.Sleep(1);` in order to see the results. Here's the complete code:

```
private void Load()
    {
        if (onLoad != null)
        {
            loading = true;
            while (true)
            {
                loading = onLoad(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                if (!loading)
                    break;

                Thread.Sleep(1); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is thread safe according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474945/is-it-safe-to-use-a-boolean-flag-to-stop-a-thread-from-running-in-c-sharp) for a similar question. As suggested by the post you also need to declare your boolean variable `volatile` so that its value is not cached. You can't declare properties `volatile` so you'll need to add a backing property and declare that volatile.

Comment: This is good information and something that I left out but as it turns out I needed to call `Thread.Sleep(1);` so that it could exit the loop, it makes loading slightly longer but it did the trick