# How to notify calling sub that QueueUserWorkItem sub is finished?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

`timerTicks` fires every second, and runs sub `CheckTableForNewRecords` as long as `IsCheckingTable = False`.

Sub `CheckTableForNewRecords` determines if my SQL table has new records, if it does, it will run sub `SQL.GetTrades` on a new thread.

I need the property `IsCheckingTable` to change to `False` only when the threaded sub `SQL.GetTrades` is finished.

How do I do this?

```
Public Sub timerTicks() Handles EventTimer.Tick
    If IsCheckingTable = False Then
        CheckTableForNewRecords()
    End If
    Timertxt.Text = Date.Now
End Sub

Public Sub CheckTableForNewRecords()
    sw.Restart()
    sw.Start()
    IsCheckingTable = True
    PR = LR
    SQL.GETlastrcrd(QueryLR, LR)
    NR = LR - PR
    LastrcrdFRM.Text = LR
    PrvLastrcrdFRM.Text = PR
    NewRecordsFRM.Text = NR
    'check table
    If NR > 0 Then
        Dim QueryRR As String = "SELECT * from(select ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by StreamingID ) as row, " & _
                                "StreamingID,WatchlistID,symbol,Bid,Ask,Last,High,Low,PrevClose,Volume,TradeTime," & _
                                "QuoteTime,TradeDate,QuoteDate,Volatility,OpenInterest,UnderlyingSymbol,CallPut,TradeVolume,TradeAmount,Trade,LastSize from optionstream) " & _
                                "as StreamingID where StreamingID between " & PR & " AND " & LR
        Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf SQL.GetTrades), QueryRR)
    End If
    IsCheckingTable = False
    TEchecktradesFRM.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `Task` instead.

Comment: Task? sorry, not familiar with it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't care about thread-safety or anything, a very naive way you could do it would be something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    Sub() 
        SQL.GetTrades()
        IsCheckingTable = True
    End Sub)
```

You may want to mark `IsCheckingTable` volatile for the reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474969/945456). You may also want a try/catch/finally inside the `QueueUserWorkItem` to make sure we reset `IsCheckingTable`.

But as SLaks commented, using Tasks available in newer versions of .NET would be better suited to what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with them yet.